# ¿Cuál sería una alternativa a logger.info() en java? o como puedo corregir este error al importar la librería?

Tags: java, spring-boot

El IDE con el que estoy trabajando es eclipse, y estoy trabajando con spring boot. Quiero visualizar en una vista nueva con el enlace /info/{id} y por consiguiente, he creado este código:
El objetivo es que al ejecutar el programa en el servidor, se muestre el objeto recuperado según el id que yo seleccione en la consola. Pero tengo un problema con "logger" y es que al importar la librería para utilizarlo, me surge lo de la imagen:

```
@GetMapping({ "/info/{id}" })
public String info(@PathVariable Integer id){
    SOLICITUD_ENTITY informacion= solicitudRepositorio.findById(id);
    logger.info("Objeto Recuperado {}", informacion);
    return "Portal/info";
}
```

El error es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya intenté cambiar "logger" por "logg" y tampoco me funciona. Alguien tendría otra solución?

Comment: El import debe estar así: **`org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.logging.Log`** yo veo que tienes además `_.logger` ¿? Considera poner también los `import` como texto, y el mensaje de error como texto, copiando y pegando. Es mejor para resolver los problemas planteados aquí.

Comment: No tiene sentido que uses un logger interno de hibernate. Si usas springboot, simplemente crea el logger en tu clase: `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ÀppController.class);` importando `org.slf4j.Logger` y `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

Comment: algo que puedes utilizar para simplificar el código es lombok que elimina el boilerplate de java